# ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads does not prevent creating more Threads manually?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on a legacy project that dates back to the pre-tpl area and I would like to double-confirm something, that `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` does not prevent creating more Threads manually.

I tried to create a small program to confirm this and seems that I am right:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        const int maximumThreadPoolWorkers = 8;
        var isThreadPoolMaxThreadsSet = ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(maximumThreadPoolWorkers, maximumThreadPoolWorkers);

        Console.WriteLine($"isThreadPoolMaxThreadsSet: {isThreadPoolMaxThreadsSet}");

        const int regularThreads = 20;
        for (var i = 0; i < regularThreads; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(DoSomethingRealllllyLong);
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    private static void DoSomethingRealllllyLong()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;

        Console.WriteLine($"Current Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} | From ThreadPool: {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}");
        while (true)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
isThreadPoolMaxThreadsSet: True
Current Thread Id: 3 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 4 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 11 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 9 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 12 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 5 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 13 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 15 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 10 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 6 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 18 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 16 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 14 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 7 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 19 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 21 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 8 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 20 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 17 | From ThreadPool: False
Current Thread Id: 22 | From ThreadPool: False
```

Would be nice if someone could double confirm whether I misunderstood something or not. that only threadpool threads are subject to the limitation forced by `SetMaxThreads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating of Thread Pool threads is managed by .Net. Thread pool threads is used for executing `Tasks`. When user runs many Tasks in parallel .Net will create new threads in thread pool automatically to increase performance. `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` limits maximum number of threads in thread pool. Threads manually created with new Thread() are not thread pool threads. So limit set by `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`is not related to manually created threads. 
[Related article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool)

Answer (score 3):

Creating a thread manually is unrelated to ThreadPool indeed. 
there is no reason it should be related by the way !

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought, the author of the legacy code I am working on seems to have some misconceptions then =/ (limitation set for no reason, since only "manually created" threads are used)

Comment: @EhouarnPerret Yes, probably.